# docker-compose.yml reboot and directive COMMAND and ENTRYPOINT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Есть файл docker-compose.yml и в нем объявлены директивы COMMAND и ENTRYPOINT.
Если сделать docker-compose restart или docker restart мойконтейнер - будут ли выполнены эти директивы повторно или они только для сборки?
Я новичок в докере, прошу сильно не пинать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будут, эти команды как раз и предназначены чтобы указать что должно быть выполнено в контейнере когда он запускается. А вот `RUN` выполняется при сборке образа.

Документация:

[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

[ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.